# child of tree with different color

Tags: nodes, tikz-styles

How to modify the color in any of the nodes in this snippet of tikz code?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=3em, every node/.style = { rounded corners, draw, 
 align=right, top color=white, bottom color=blue!30}]] 
 \node {000} 
  child { node {000}}
  child { node {100}} 
  child { node {010}}
  child { node {001}
     child { node {000}
         child { node {000}} 
         child { node {100}}
         child { node {010}}
         child { node {001}}
         child { node {110}}
         child { node {011}}
         child { node {101}}
         child { node {111}} } 
     child { node {100}} 
     child { node {010}} 
     child { node {001}}
     child { node {101}} 
     child { node {011}}
     child { node {110}} 
     child { node {111}} }
 child { node {101}} 
 child { node {011}}
 child { node {110}}
 child { node {111}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean. However, I made up this small modification for you.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
stdNode/.style={rounded corners, draw, align=right},
greenRed/.style={stdNode, top color=green, bottom color=red},
blueRed/.style={stdNode, top color=blue, bottom color=red}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=3em, every node/.style={rounded corners, draw, align=right, top color=white, bottom color=blue!30}]] 
 \node {000} 
  child { node[red] {000}}
  child { node[top color=green,bottom color=red!30] {100}} 
  child { node[greenRed] {010}}
  child { node[blueRed] {001}
     child { node {000}
         child { node {000}} 
         child { node {100}}
         child { node {010}}
         child { node {001}}
         child { node {110}}
         child { node {011}}
         child { node {101}}
         child { node {111}} } 
     child { node {100}} 
     child { node {010}} 
     child { node {001}}
     child { node {101}} 
     child { node {011}}
     child { node {110}} 
     child { node {111}} }
 child { node {101}} 
 child { node {011}}
 child { node {110}}
 child { node {111}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I highly recommend the *pgfmanual.pdf* on https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf.

[image]

Just because one can choose these strange colors does not imply that one should.